# error in flutter using onTab()

Tags: flutter

This is the error message

```
compiler message: Unhandled exception:
Crash when compiling file:///C:/Users/Anton/AndroidStudioProjects            /kontaktdaten_app/lib/Pages/landingPage.dart,
at character offset 136:
lib/Pages/landingPage.dart:9:16: Internal problem: Unhandled () → void =>     dart.core::print("Tapped") in defaultTreeNode.
    onTap: () => print("Tapped"),
```

This is my Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      child:  InkWell(
        onTap: () => print("Tapped"),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("Tap to Start!", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50.0)),
      ],
    ),
  )
);
  }
}
```

I update flutter to the newest version but it didnt woork. so pls help me:D ty

Comment: In an older Project i build last week, the onTab() Function works without Problems

Comment: What is your newest version? `flutter --version`

Comment: 0.2.8 but i build a new Project with the same Code and now it works. I dont know why it works now

Comment: Try clearing the build directory of the old project (flutter clean) and rebuilding - it might have cached something from a previous build that caused the problem.